# Validation check Excluding VAT - VAT and Total Amount

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax

I'm trying to make a reconciliation/validation check if two numbers, one excluding VAT and one VAT equal to the total.

I have the following df:

```
    Document Type   Factuurnummer   FactuurdatumKvK    ExclBTW   BTW        Totaal  Vervaldatum Item    Omschrijving    ... Betalingsvoorwaarden    Email   Postalcode_Finalp   Postalcodestringp   Cityp   Countryp    Postalcode_Final    Postalcodestring    City    Country
0   NaN 44  2021-02-27  58782494                       1700.00  357.00  2057.00 2021-03-13  

I've tried the following code:
#validation check
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if df1['Totaal'][i].astype('float') == (df1['ExclBTW'][i].astype('float') + df1['BTW'][i].astype('float')):
        df1['Totaal'].astype('float') == df1['Totaal'].astype('float')
    else:
        df1['Totaal'] = "ERROR!"
```

However, getting an invalid ValueError..  What would be the best according to you guys?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-a461c3c9030f> in <module>
    113 #validation check
    114 for i, row in df1.iterrows():
--> 115     if df1['Totaal'][i].astype('float') == (df1['ExclBTW'][i].astype('float') + df1['BTW'][i].astype('float')):
    116         df1['Totaal'].astype('float') == df1['Totaal'].astype('float')
    117     else:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do if `if` statement runs?

Comment: Either maintain the current value (in case of accurate Totaal) or place an error in case of no matching

Comment: What do you want to do if it’s true? I think you can just do `np.where(df1['Totaal'].astype('float') == (df1['ExclBTW'].astype('float') + df1['BTW'].astype('float')), True, False,)`

Comment: Change the type of the whole column you're working with. Another way would be to cast to float: `float(df1['Totaal'][i])`. But the former is better.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! @PraysonW.Daniel, tried your code, however, it does not return True or False unfortunately.

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: It returned the same values. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas allows you to do those operation in a vectorize way

```py
# have numpy for efficiency
import numpy as np

...
# assuming  no missing values
# np.where(condition, value_if_condition_true, value_if_condition_false, [default_value])

np.where(df1['Totaal'].astype('float') == (df1['ExclBTW'].astype('float') + df1['BTW'].astype('float')), True, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `astype` and `apply`:

```
df.loc[:, ['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']] = df[['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df['new_col'] = df[['ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal']].\
                  apply(lambda x: x['Totaal'] if x['Totaal'] == (x['ExclBTW'] + x['BTW']) else 'ERROR!', axis=1)
```

Comment: Happly to help!
Kindly give it an upvote if you can.

Comment: I did so! When having missing values I get the following error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: do you have any recommendations for this? :)

Comment: Yes. This happened because in the ''ExclBTW', 'BTW','Totaal'' there are some values that cannot be converted to numerical. But you can use `pd.to_numeric(error='coerce')` to force them to become numeric or `NaN` values. I edited my answer. Please let me know how it works.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please take a look, and let me know if it's working.